# How do I convert a PHP regex with a lookbehind to Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, lookbehind

Javascript doesn't support lookbehinds in regexes. How do I convert the following PHP regex to Javascript?

```
regPattern="(?<!\\)\\x"
```

Here is the test case (in Node.js):

```
var str = '{"key":"abc \\x123 \xe2\x80\x93 xyz"}'
var newStr = str.replace(/regPattern/g, '\\u')
console.log(newStr); // output: '{"key":"abc \\x123 \ue2\u80\u93 xyz"}'
```

`\\x123` doesn't match because it contains `\\x`, but `\x` matches.

Comment: Your `str` is not a `String`.

Comment: Now, your string is `{"key":"abc \x123 â xyz"}`, so, `.replace(/\\x/g, '//u')` will produce `{"key":"abc //u123 â xyz"}`. Are you sure you posted the *correct* string literal?

Comment: right, I've corrected the str to '{"key":"abc \\x123 \xe2\x80\x93 xyz"}', which is a string now

/\\x/g have the following output

'{"key":"abc \\u123 \ue2\u80\u93 xyz"}'

Comment: note, \\x123 is not a match

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var newStr = str.replace(/([^\\]|^)\\x/g, '$1\\u');
```

In other words, match the `^` (start of string) or any non-`\` character, followed by `\x`, capturing the first character in capture group 1.

Then replace the whole 3-character matched group with capture group 1, followed by `\u`.

For example, in `abc?\x`, the string `?\x` will be matched, and capture group 1 will be `?`. So we replace the match (`?\x`) with `$1\u`, which evaluates to `?\u`. So `abc?\x` -> `abc?\u`.